# An error appears under my project name but no error exists?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna

What basically happens is an error (little red cross) appears under my project name as if there was an error somewhere. When I look into my project, no errors, and when I run my code, no errors, it works perfectly fine.
Can someone explain to me how I can fix it? And what it means?

I'm using Eclipse Luna.

[image]

Comment: I've seen this with eclipse so many times, I've lost count. The best I can say is, eclipse is confused, it usually figures it out eventually. Sometimes refreshing the project files can fix it.

Comment: Open the `markers view`, and check what errors are there. And now, you can add images.

Comment: try refreshing the panel (several times) - one of the 'features' of Eclipse that drove me away from it

Comment: never happened to me and i'm a heavy user, can you provide a screenshot ?

Comment: Try a `Project > Clean... > Clean projects selected below > Start a build immediately (Build only the selected projects)` if cleaning and building your project isn't that expensive.

Comment: Hmm.. Still appears :/ I added a screenshot.