# A warning appears under my project name?

Tags: java, eclipse-luna

I posted a questions a couple of days ago about eclipse notifying me of an error I didn't have.
[An error appears under my project name but no error exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27724969/an-error-appears-under-my-project-name-but-no-error-exists)

I fixed that error but now I face another problem. Under my project name, a little yellow warning sign appears. My program runs fine though. Can someone explain to me what it means or how to get rid of it?

[image: Here's a screenshot of what happens:]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click `Window > Show View > Problems` to open the Problem View. This should list any warnings/errors showing up in Package Manager.